# Retrieving the BackendUser from BackendUserAuthentication

Tags: typo3

I'm trying to develop an extension that adds a Button to the ClearCache menu in the TYPO3 Backend. In a large installation with multiple domains, non-admin users need a button to clear the page cache for their domain, but only of those pages that they have access to. The default `options.clearCache.pages = 1` instead flushes the whole Frontend Cache of the installation.

I've gotten so far as to calling a method in a custom class `ClearCacheHook`, that implements `\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Toolbar\ClearCacheActionsHookInterface`.

I next need to get a list of all page uids the BackendUser has access to, which is done with `$backendUser->getDbMountPoints()`. All the docs speak of a global variable $BE_USER, but this isn't set for me. I have a `$GLOBALS['BE_USER']`, but that is of the class `BackendUserAuthentication`.

I can't figure out how to resolve the `BackendUser` from the `BackendUserAuthentication`. Theres the BackendUser uid in the object so I tried initializing a `TYPO3\\CMS\\Beuser\\Domain\\Repository\\BackendUserRepository` via the ObjectManager, but that fails.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more background for your setup? Maybe this could be solved e.g. with cache tags instead.

Comment: Its an installation with about 120 sub sites. Every on of those has at least one distinct user. Almost all pages are cachable, I use nc_staticfilecache. The standard page cache flush button causes horrible slowdowns across the entire site, tho.

Comment: As an alternative on writing your own extension, you could have a look at EXT:sm_clearcachecm. This extension lets your backend users delete the cache on the pages they have access to in the backend.

Comment: @cephei_vv Thats where I got the Idea from, but unfortually I'm dealing with users that need something more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

I'll focus on the more specific tasks: Create an instance of BackendUserRepository and create an instance of BackendUser from uid.

You might have a look at the [UsernameViewHelper.php](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/4062df63f917c37d79bfd6307153734811ab4ac1/typo3/sysext/belog/Classes/ViewHelpers/UsernameViewHelper.php#L65) class of be_log in the TYPO3 core.

specifically this:

```php
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\BackendUserRepository;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;

...

$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
$backendUserRepository = $objectManager->get(BackendUserRepository::class);
/** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\BackendUser $user */
$user = $backendUserRepository->findByUid($uid);
```

If there is something, I don't find in the documentation, I sometimes look at existing extensions. A good candidate is the [news](https://github.com/georgringer/news) extensions. Other good candidates are, of course, the TYPO3 source code.